# Why is it better to ask all my questions separately, and not all at once?

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions

So I have a bunch of questions about something. If they're all related to each other, then wouldn't it be better to ask them all together? I don't want to spam the site with all my questions!

Answer (score 5):

Never worry about spamming the site with too many questions. As long as the questions have not been asked before, and are written with acceptable quality, they're more than welcome here. Questions are what make this site grow.

There are several reasons why asking each question separately is better, even if they're related to each other.

1. **More questions increase the size of the site, and draw in more users who can answer your question.**

   In order to attract attention, we not only need to have content, but we need to have active content. That means we need new questions coming in, and answers going out constantly. The worst thing for us to have is static content.

   So when a sudden influx of questions come in, that is a good thing for the site because it's a sudden influx of fresh, ***new***, content. Having this new content draws users, some of whom might be able to answers those questions.
2. **Single questions are easily searched and indexed by search engines. Which will draw in more users who can answer your question.**

   Stack Exchange is not just for you, it's for everyone. So when someone else is looking for a question we want them to be able to find it easily. That's pretty hard to do when the question is hidden in the middle of another question. Simplifying questions makes it easier for everyone.
3. **You will be more likely to get higher quality answers.**

   If you look at some of the answers on this site, you'll notice that some of them go into great detail, which is great and exactly what we want on the site. But, that sometimes means an answer is fairly long in order to fit all that detail.

   If you have several questions together, then a person answering might be more inclined to summarize each answer rather than writing it out in detail. Not only so that they aren't spending hours writing an answer, but so that the answer doesn't become so long that nobody will read it.
4. **You will be more likely to get answers in general.**

   Similar to the previous section, people will just be more likely to write an answer to your question if it's a single question. It doesn't bother me to write an answer in a couple minutes, but if I have to take ten minutes or more to write my answer, it had better be a really good question. Otherwise I'm either going to skip it, or tell myself I'm going to answer it later and end up forgetting about it.

   Remember, everyone here is volunteering their own time as they see fit. Keeping it quick and simple makes it easier on everyone.

   There's also a good chance that people who could answer some of the questions won't, because only complete answers are encouraged on Stack Exchange. Writing each question separately keeps from excluding people who might not know the answer to one of your questions.

Comment: Yeah. a healthy beta site gets [at least 15 new questions per day.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/44686/pets) This site is getting 3.6. I definitely wouldn't worry about asking too many questions. :)

Answer (score 5):

The main reason is so that people who are able to answer SOME but not ALL of your questions can

- give you answers;
- receive appropriate votes for their answers;
- have you accept an answer if it's the right answer for one of your questions.

Lumping multiple questions together prevents all of this, and may dissuade people from answering if they're unable to answer EVERYTHING that you want to know.