# Should I split a symptoms question into individual symptoms, if so, should I leave the original?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Option 1: Single long question:

- Should I be concerned about my cats development because of A, B, C?

Option 2: Multiple small questions:

- What is normal A for a cat?
- What is normal B for a cat?
- What is normal C for a cat?

If I go option 1 the question is long and specific to me, *but* it opens up the valuable possibility for a great general behavior answer that contains that information and more.

If I go option 2 I kill the possibility for a comprehensive answer, but the questions are easier to find, more generally applicable, and easier to give specific answers to.

Note that this isn't the classic multiple unrelated questions in one post (at least I don't *think* it is) - A, B, C are distinctly related reasons for the question (think e.g. asking about a collection of possibly related symptoms of a single problem vs. asking about each symptom individually). E.g. "My dog is gaining weight and losing hair; does he have a thyroid problem?" vs. "What is the normal weight for a dog? What is the normal hair loss rate for a dog?" This fuzzy boundary is not covered by [Why is it better to ask all my questions separately, and not all at once?](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1837/why-is-it-better-to-ask-all-my-questions-separately-and-not-all-at-once).

I think there are good cases for both options. Which should I choose?

Also, suppose I have [already done option 1](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5746/kitten-development-spatial-awareness) but decide to do option 2 instead. Should I delete the original or can I leave them all? If I delete the original there is potentially less redundant information and noise on the site and my option 2 questions become duplicates of it, but if I leave it I still leave the possibility for a comprehensive answer.

Comment: To split your existing question, edit the original question to have only one question, then ask additional questions to cover the additional topics.

Comment: @Zaralynda Not a duplicate. See the bit I just added, in particular: "Note that this isn't the classic multiple unrelated questions in one post (at least I don't think it is) - A, B, C are distinctly related reasons for the question (think e.g. asking about a collection of possibly related symptoms of a single problem vs. asking about each symptom individually)." See also the linked question, which does not fall into the clear cut boundaries described by the linked duplicate.